# p-adic asymptotic analysis

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

There is a huge field of asymptotic expansions and such over the real and complex fields (see Bender and Orszag, or Copson, or Whittaker and Watson). How different is the theory over p-adic fields? And is there a good introduction, with lots of examples, somewhere?

Comment: I do not know of any intro on this... but/and, having thought about the archimedean case (!?!) in recent years, I wonder what things you're wanting...

Comment: @paulgarrett Perhaps asymptotic expansions for functions satisfying p-adic differential equations?

Comment: @Kimball I would certainly not say no anything on that, but my original motivation is estimating integrals (in my case, over $p$-adic Lie groups, but that has a lot of extra baggage, so it would be good to know if there were anything like steepest descent, stationary phase, or whatever)